# Binomial PMF not working! (real world application)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I calculated the probability of an event k to be

p(k) = (s+.005/n + 2), where s is number of times k has happened, n is number of trials that have happened

I try to determine what the chances of k happening once in n trials:

f[n_] := ((n!)/(n - 1)!) (1.005 /(n + 2)) ((1 - (1.005/(n + 2)))^(n - 
      1))

but.. it doesn't work!

For example f[1] = 0.335, f[800] = 0.368

What's the problem here? I took the probability mass function for binomial distributions, substituted k=1, p=(1+.005/n+2) and it's simply not doing the job!

Comment: could I just sum the probability over n trials instead?

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution can be used to determine the probability that exactly $k$ out of $n$ independent and identical trials will succeed.  If the probability that a trial succeeds actually depends on how many trials you've already carried out, then the trials are not *identical*.  If, in addition, the probability of success depends on how many of the previous trials succeeded, then the trials are not *independent* either.  The binomial distribution simply doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: I don't think the underlying probability actually changes.. but the only way I could estimate probability was by using the Rule of Succession.. which DOES. If binomial isn't a good fit, then what is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem.  Your success probability depends on $n$, and decreases as $n$ increases.

In this case, your success probability is converging to zero just fast enough that the probability of observing exactly one success is roughly constant.

Note that you should be very careful about summing over $n$, since the success probability is different for different values of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, why does F[1] admit 33% probability of the event, while p(K) says 0.17% probability?

Comment: Where do you get $p(K)=0.17$?  When $n=1$, you have $p(k)=(1.005/3)=0.335$.  Has something gone wrong with the parentheses somewhere? (I assume that you meant $$p_n=\frac{s+0.005}{n+2}.$$  I really don't know how to interpret your $s$ term, so I am just using $s=1$.)

Comment: shouldn't s = 0, since we are calculating the probability of the first event occurence?